# Unable to push on Bitbucket because after clicking grant access it redirects to localhost

Tags: bitbucket

I am facing issue to push my repository on bitbucket. After providing the user email and password Atlassian redirects to a page for two step authorization. And When I click grant access it redirect to localhost 34016. And localhost 34016 always remains down. What is the reason behind in this case ? And How to fix this issue?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed this issue.

For me the Error is:

This site can’t provide a secure connection
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

My Solution:

1. Open an incognito Window
2. Change HTTPS to HTTP
3. Refresh page and I'm authenticated